# Metrics of redis and solr in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-boot-actuator

I have services built in spring boot 2.0.2. I`m using redis and solrj.

Now if i want to get metrics of redis and solr. It **don`t show** in

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
```

Is there any way e.g making custom endpoint to get redis and solr metrics?

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

The code shown in Mark Bramnik's answer doesn't specifically give you timing for Redis client calls, it gives you timing for `doSomethingInMyCode` method, which can be different.

Micrometer support seems to be available in the Lettuce 6.1 release.

```
MeterRegistry meterRegistry = …;
MicrometerOptions options = MicrometerOptions.create();
ClientResources resources = ClientResources.builder().commandLatencyRecorder(new MicrometerCommandLatencyRecorder(meterRegistry, options)).build();

RedisClient client = RedisClient.create(resources);
```

https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/index.html#command.latency.metrics.micrometer

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it should be possible.

Spring boot 2's default metrics framework is [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs)

When this framework is integrated into spring boot application (via starter as usual), any metrics reported to micrometer will immediately appear in spring boot actuator.

So the question is whether the redis/solrj integration expose Metrics or not.

If they are not, you'll have to understand what exactly you want to measure and plug in the integration.

Here is the example:

```
import io.micrometer.core.annotation;

@Timed("my-redis-calls")
public void doSomethingInMyCode() {
    //call redis here 
}
```

Of course, there is also a programmatic interface, using annotations in not mandatory